# Javascript configuration object advice

Tags: javascript

This isn't a problem code, it's more of an advice question. I found the below code on Better Practices for Javascript.

If I had this code below, what would be the usage for it the script to pull labels and settings etc.

```
carousel = function(){
   var config = {
      CSS:{
         classes:{
            current:'current',
            scrollContainer:'scroll'
         },
         IDs:{
            maincontainer:'carousel'
         }
      }
      labels:{
         previous:'back',
         next:'next',
         auto:'play'
      }
      settings:{
         amount:5,
         skin:'blue',
         autoplay:false
      }
   };
   function init(){
   };
   function scroll(){
   };
   function highlight(){
   };
   return {config:config,init:init}
}();
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to do?

Comment: Hi Beardy. Not quite sure what you mean by "what would be the usage for it the script to pull labels and settings etc." could you clarify?

Comment: How would you call the script above to work on a web page

Comment: It's a self-invoking function, which means it'll execute as soon as the page loads.  See [this article](http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/) for some more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've essentially detailed a JavaScript design pattern called the [Revealing Module Pattern](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/08/02/techniques-strategies-and-patterns-for-structuring-javascript-code-revealing-module-pattern.aspx) - it's a really nice pattern to get to grips with as it allows you to write JS in a more OOP fashion.

To access the properties simple traverse through the object, for example:

```
carousel.config.labels.previous
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9LCYz/)